# Access MVC web application from other computer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I just published my mvc application on IIS server and its working correctly and i can access it through webbrowser. The problem is within same network i canlt access it from other host for which the server is visible. Error i receive when trying to access is saying:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

P.S How to check what port was assigned to my web application and eventually how to change it?

Comment: What type of `Authentication` you have set? `Forms` or `windows`? if any?

Comment: What are the `Network` permissions of your IIS ?

Comment: Authentication: annonymous - enabled, forms - disabled, wdinwso auth - disabled   P.S How to check "network permission"?